# Vue js lost jquery effects on router-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I am trying to set up a login page followed by the main panel , which is adminlte , I added a router-view in the main component switching between login page and home page on login action

this scenario makes the home page losing dropdown effects , datatables and a lot of jquery actions
, but when I set the main component to be the home page , it works fine ..

I think the problem is when mounting javascript files to the document , but I dont know the solution

```
export const scripts = {
    script1() {
        var arr = [
            './static/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js',
            './static/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js',
            './static/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js',
            './static/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        ];
        arr.forEach(item => {
            var plugin;
            plugin = document.createElement("script");
            plugin.setAttribute(
                "src",
                item
            );
            plugin.async = false;
            document.head.appendChild(plugin);
        });
    },
    adminlte() {
        var arr = [
            './static/dist/js/adminlte.js'
        ];

        arr.forEach(item => {
            var plugin;
            plugin = document.createElement("script");
            plugin.setAttribute(
                "src",
                item
            );
            plugin.async = false;
            document.head.appendChild(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

this code is imported in the components and executed at mounted() event

thanks for help

Comment: Are only the animation effects lost or some critical actions too?

Comment: what I noticed is the animation , for now .. clicking a dropdown menu wont open it unless I put the component as the main component , no in a router-view

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs help us to create a web project without focus on the DOM, and jquery is used to operate DOM. So it's best to give up jquery when you decide to use vuejs.

Comment: Ok so what can be the solution ??